# Fit the whole Screen with two dynamic Widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Within a **Column** I have two Widgets: **TableCalendar** and a **Container** that contains a **ListView.builder**. Both have dynamic sizes.

I want my Container to fill the remaining size of the screen that is left from the calendar.

I thought that I could regulate this wrapping both Widgets with the **Expanded** Widget, but that only leads to an error.

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex
>   children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are
>   unbounded.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(
              events: _events, //fixme: here is the problem
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.twoWeeks,
              calendarController: _controller,
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(),
              headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                centerHeaderTitle: true,
                formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.pinkAccent.shade100,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                formatButtonShowsNext: false,
              ),
              startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
              onDaySelected: (date, events) {
                setState(() {
                  _listOfShiftsPerGivenDay = events;
                });
              },
              builders: CalendarBuilders(
                  selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        color: Colors.pink,
//                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: Text(
                          date.day.toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                  todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        color: Colors.teal.shade100,
                        child: Text(
                          date.day.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                  markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
                    final children = <Widget>[];

                    if (events.isNotEmpty) {
                      children.add(
                        Positioned(
                          right: 1,
                          bottom: 1,
                          child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return children;
                  }),
            ),
            Container(
              //fixme: the hight needs to be variable
              height: 200.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _listOfShiftsPerGivenDay.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: _events[_controller.selectedDay][index],
//                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: you can use a `Flexible()` widget along with a `ListView()`. that should achieve what you're looking for

Comment: @abiudrn I wrapped each of the **TableCalendar** and **Container** with the **Flexible** Widget and gave them the respectable flex values of 2 and 1. I got the following Error: *RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.*

Comment: I had what I think was a similar problem and solved it by wrapping the ListView in a Flexible (with no flex value) and wrapping the parent of the ListView (in my case the parent was a Column widget) in a Flexible, again with no flex value. However, after looking at MarsGoatz' answer it seems that wrapping both the ListView and its parents in Expanded will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the parent of the main Column at the beginning? Is it another Column?

If that is the case, then try wrapping the Column at the beginning with Expanded, that will force a height constraint to its children, then you can use Expanded on Container.

```
child: Expanded(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[

      TableCalendar();

      Expanded(
        child: Container()
      )
  ])
```

I have written an [article](https://medium.com/@sid.310/flutter-box-constraints-101-the-basics-bd0babe650f9) on Medium on why this might happen, if you want to know more.

Comment: At the top level, I have a **Scaffold**. Then I have a body of **SingleChildScrollView** and its child is the **Column** mentioned above. So the **TableCalendar** is the first child of the Column and then the second is the **Container**.

Comment: Got it! So SingleChildScrollView doesn't pass in the height constraint which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrap your `ListView()` in an Expanded?

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[

    TableCalendar();

    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder()
    )
])
```

Comment: Getting an error: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.